# Play .mp3 using MediaPlayer just one time and not loop

Tags: android

So I have a `.mp3 in` assets folder (I plan to have many more later) and I have a simple click associated to play it:

```
public static MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDrum);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                PlayMusic(v);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void PlayMusic(View v) throws IOException {
    try {
        if (m.isPlaying()) {
            m.stop();
            m.release();
            m = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(Kit.KickDrum);
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        m.prepare();
        m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        m.setLooping(true);
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, every-time  I try to click the button, I the music plays in loop! I just need it to **play once and stop**! How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: isn't it obvious that you requested it to loop in your code? `m.setLooping(true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting it for looping using `m.setLooping(true);` change it to false

Comment: Gosh! How did I miss it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
try {
            Uri mp3 = Uri.parse("url");
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, mp3);
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

// onCompletionListerner

```
private OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
    }
 };
```

Comment: long turn for a simple problem, keep it simple